# How to get multiple user inputs in a while loop

Tags: c#

I cannot get my while loop to ask the user to input another word.

I'm a beginner and am having trouble seeing where my error is. I have searched online for similar solutions to no avail. Here's what I have:

```
Console.WriteLine("Which word is the longest?");
int howMany = 5;//Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter {0} words and I will tell you which is the longest", howMany);
string userWord = Console.ReadLine();
int counter = 0;

while (counter < howMany)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Enter a word {0} > ", counter + 1);
     string wordLength = (userWord.Length).ToString();
     counter++;
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the readline into the loop,
Your program is executing and then reading the line after.

```
            Console.WriteLine("Which word is the longest?");
        int howMany = 5;//Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter {0} words and I will tell you which is the longest", howMany);
        string LongestWord = "";
        int counter = 0;

        while (counter < howMany)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a word {0} > ", counter + 1);
            string temp = Console.ReadLine();
            if (temp.Length > LongestWord.Length) // check if the new word is longer than the current longest word
            {
                LongestWord = temp;
            }
            counter++; //update counter
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"{LongestWord} is the longest word"); // after exiting the loop, print the longest word
```

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly. I'll be comparing what you did to what I did to fill some gaps in my learning.

Comment: You're welcome, I know how difficult it can be trying to learn on your own!! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

No matter which pattern you implement here, you will need to read the user input again, which you are not doing.

```
while (counter < howMany)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Enter a word {0} > ", counter + 1);
     string wordLength = (userWord.Length).ToString();
     counter++;
     userWord = Console.ReadLine(); // yehaa
}
```

Or seemingly this seems like a job for a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Enter a word {0} > ", counter + 1);
   userWord = Console.ReadLine(); // yehaa
   wordLength = (userWord.Length).ToString();
   ...
}
```

***Note**: I am a little unclear of your logic or how you need it implemented. However, I think you can see what's going on here.*